# how to create personalised item warsaw beamer

Tags: beamer, formatting, itemize

Am using the `warsaw` theme in `beamer`. I want to show this item form:

[image]

I try this code but it doesn't show me the best result :

```
\begin{itemize}[font=\color{cyan} \large, label=\ding{118}]
\item  first item.
\item  second item.
\end{itemize}
```

How can I correct it please?

Comment: For best results, start with `\documentclass` and remember the `document` environment. LaTeX gets upset otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use an [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)-like interface. You need to `set` the `beamer` `theme` for `itemize`ed `item`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{warsaw}

\usepackage{pifont}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\ding{118}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item first item.
    \item second item.
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You can also change the colour to suit your needs:

[image]

```
...
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{cyan}\ding{118}}
...
```

The setting of a `beamer` template like this one is macro-based, and therefore can be grouped in order to localize the change:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{warsaw}

\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}

  \begingroup
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{cyan}\ding{118}}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item first item.
    \item second item.
  \end{itemize}
  \endgroup

  \begin{itemize}
    \item first item.
    \item second item.
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: perfect but i want to change just one item list and let the others as default

Comment: @SihemHcine: See the updated answer that uses a group to limit the scope of the change.